# Magento2:In admin form after save image couldn't save into database and directory

Tags: magento2.3.3

enter code`Install schema.php

namespace Magik\Helloworld\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

```
    // Get tutorial_simplenews table
    $tableName = $installer->getTable('magik_helloworld_slider');
    // Check if the table already exists
    if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
        // Create tutorial_simplenews table
        $table = $installer->getConnection()
            ->newTable($tableName)
            ->addColumn(
                'id',
                Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'identity' => true,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'primary' => true
                ],
                'ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'imagename',
                Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                'name'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'url',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                ['nullable'=> true],
                'URL Link'
            )
            // ->addColumn(
            //     'image',
            //     \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            //     '255',
            //     ['nullable' =>false],
            //     'Banner Image'
            // )
            ->addColumn(
                'summary',
                Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                'Summary'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'description',
                Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                'Description'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'store_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                null,
                ['identity' =>false,'unsigned' =>true, 'nullable' =>false],
                'Store_Id'
            )
            // ->addColumn(
            //     'order',
            //     \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            //     null,
            //     ['nullable' =>true],
            //     'Sort Order'
            // )
            ->addColumn(
                'created_at',
                Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false],
                'Created At'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'status',
                Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
                'Status'
            )
            ->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFKName('magik_helloworld_slider','store_id','store','store_id'),'store_id',
            $installer->getTable('store'),
            'store_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_NO_ACTION)
            ->addIndex(
            $setup->getIdxName(
            $installer->getTable('magik_helloworld_slider'),
            ['imagename'],
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
            ),
            ['imagename'],
            ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT]
        )->setComment('magik_helloworld_slider')
            ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
            ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }

    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

}
` here[image: blcok file[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGJvI.png)I have created admin grid form. After saving form image couldn't get save into the database and directory.Other records save successfully in the database.

Comment: please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269883/in-admin-form-after-edit-and-save-a-form-in-db-already-stored-image-save-as-bla?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I think you have to change $result['url'] to $result['file']

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($files['image'])) {
                if (isset($files['image']['name']) and (file_exists($files['image']['tmp_name']))) {
                    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
                    $uploader = $this->mediaStorageFileUploader->create(['fileId' => $files['image']]);
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                    $path = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath(
                        'simple_image/'
                    );

                    $result = $uploader->save($path, $files['image']['name']);

                    $image = 'simple_image' . $result['file'];
                } else {
                    $value = $data['image']['value'];
                    if (isset($data['image']['delete'])) {
                        $imageDelete = $data['image']['delete'];
                        $image = (isset($imageDelete) && $imageDelete == 1) ? '' : $value;
                    } else {
                        $image = $value;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Create a folder in /pub/media/simple_image folder and check it with the above source code.
Add new column-like and change the column name which you want.

->addColumn(
                    'image',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    [
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'default' => null,
                    ],
                    'Image'
                )

Comment: okk ..I will try

Comment: You must need to create a folder in pub/media/sample_image.

Comment: This Module is the UI component? If UI component then we need to make changes for UI component. For UI component we need to add entries in the di.xml file.

Comment: I have created module using block method without ui component.

Comment: Okay, Is it possible to share your table install schema?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Add new Field like and change your column which you want.
->addColumn(
                    'image',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    [
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'default' => null,
                    ],
                    'Image'
                )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105436/discussion-between-shital-and-user-61205).

Comment: guys suggest me answer about this problem.