# HTTP ERROR 500 - Product page Only

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

I freshly started working on Magento 2 using Cloudways hosting services.

I wanted to add my first product today but after adding it, I faced HTTP ERROR 500.

You can see it at : https://www.supplyarmy.com/us-t-shirt.html

Here is my Apache Error Log:

> *[Wed Nov 06 14:12:04.004860 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 11166] [client 127.0.0.1:54952] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal
>   error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getData() on null in
>   /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml:18\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59):
>   include()\n#1
>   /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271):
>   Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details),
>   '/home/321257.cl...', Array)\n#2
>   /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/321257.cl...')\n#3
>   /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(668):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()\n#4
>   /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukga...\n',

referer: https://www.supplyarmy.com/vetements.html

I am a bit lost and tried couple things but it did not work.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

PS: I use Magento ver. 2.3.1

Edit: Here is my details files as requested.

I changed some of the code based on this thread:

[Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getData() on null](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279835/uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-getdata-on-null)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
<?php
    $porto_helper = $this->helper('Smartwave\Porto\Helper\Data');
    $_helper = $this->helper('Smartwave\Porto\Helper\Customtabs');
    $product_config = $porto_helper->getConfig('porto_settings/product');
    $static_block_tab = $product_config['custom_block_next_tab'];
    $custom_block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block');
    $_product = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Magento\Framework\Registry::class)->registry('product');
    $page_type = $_product->getData('product_page_type');
    if(!$page_type)
        $page_type = isset($_config['product_page_type'])?$_config['product_page_type']:'';
    if($custom_block) {
        $custom_block->setBlockId($static_block_tab);
    }
    $tab_style = "";
    if(isset($product_config['tab_style']) && $product_config['tab_style'])
        $tab_style = $product_config['tab_style'];
    if($page_type == 'wide_grid')
        $tab_style = 'vertical';
?>
    <?php if($product_config['tab_full_background']):?>
    <div class="move-product-tab">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="<?php if(!$page_type && $custom_block && $static_block_tab):?>col-md-9<?php else:?>col-md-12<?php endif;?>">
    <?php endif;?>
                <div class="product info detailed <?php echo $tab_style; ?> <?php if($page_type == 'sticky_right'): ?>fullwidth-row<?php endif; ?>">
                <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
                <?php if(!$tab_style || $tab_style != "sticky"): ?>
                    <div class="product data items <?php if($page_type == 'sticky_right'): ?>container<?php endif; ?>" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
                        <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                            <?php
                            $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                            if (!trim($html)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                            $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                            ?>
                            <div class="data item title"
                                 aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title"
                                 data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>">
                                <a class="data switch"
                                   tabindex="-1"
                                   data-toggle="switch"
                                   href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"
                                   id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title">
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                        <?php
                        if($custom_cms_tabs = $_helper->getCustomTabs($_product())) {
                            $i = 1;
                            foreach($custom_cms_tabs as $_item) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="data item title"
                                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i;?>-title"
                                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i;?>">
                                    <a class="data switch"
                                       tabindex="-1"
                                       data-toggle="switch"
                                       href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i; ?>"
                                       id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i;?>-title">
                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item['tab_title']; ?></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i; ?>" data-role="content">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item['tab_content']; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php elseif($tab_style && $tab_style == "sticky"): ?>
                    <div class="product data items">
                        <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                            <?php
                            $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                            if (!trim($html)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                            $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                            $alias = str_replace(".","_",$alias);
                            ?>
                            <div class="data item title">
                                <a class="data switch" href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                        <?php
                        if($custom_cms_tabs = $_helper->getCustomTabs($_product())) {
                            $i = 1;
                            foreach($custom_cms_tabs as $_item) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="data item title">
                                    <a class="data switch" href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i; ?>">
                                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item['tab_title']; ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                            <?php
                            $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                            if (!trim($html)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                            $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                            $alias = str_replace(".","_",$alias);
                            ?>
                            <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                        <?php
                        if($custom_cms_tabs = $_helper->getCustomTabs($_product())) {
                            $i = 1;
                            foreach($custom_cms_tabs as $_item) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i; ?>">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item['tab_content']; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    require([
                        'jquery'
                    ], function ($) {
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            <?php if($tab_style && $tab_style == "vertical"): ?>
                            $(".product.info.detailed.vertical .product.data.items .data.item.title").off("classadded").on("classadded",function(){
                                $(this).parent().css("min-height",$(this).next().outerHeight()+"px");
                            });
                            <?php elseif($tab_style && $tab_style == "sticky"): ?>
                            var sticky_tabs;
                            var is_sticky = false;
                            $(window).scroll(function(){
                                if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(".product.info.detailed").offset().top-50){
                                    if(!is_sticky){
                                        $(".product.info.detailed.sticky").before('<div class="product-tabs-container"><div class="container"></div></div>');
                                        $(".product.info.detailed.sticky .product.data.items > .item.title").each(function(){
                                            $(".product-tabs-container > .container").append($(this).clone().detach());
                                        });
                                        $(".product-tabs-container .item.title > a").off("click").on("click", function(){
                                            $($(this).attr("href")).scrollToMe();
                                            return false;
                                        });
                                        <?php if ($porto_helper->getConfig('porto_settings/header/sticky_header')): ?>
                                        $(".product-tabs-container").addClass("has-sticky-header");
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if ($porto_helper->getConfig('porto_settings/header/mobile_sticky_header')): ?>
                                        $(".product-tabs-container").addClass("has-mobile-sticky-header");
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        is_sticky = true;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $(".product-tabs-container").remove();
                                    is_sticky = false;
                                }
                            });
                            $(".product.info.detailed.sticky .product.data.items > .item.title > a").off("click").on("click", function(){
                                $($(this).attr("href")).scrollToMe();
                                return false;
                            });
                            $(".product-reviews-summary .reviews-actions a.action.view").off("click").on("click", function(){
                                $("#reviews").scrollToMe();
                                return false;
                            });
                            $(".product-reviews-summary .reviews-actions a.action.add").off("click").on("click", function(){
                                $("#review-form").scrollToMe();
                                return false;
                            });
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                </div>
    <?php if($product_config['tab_full_background']):?>
            </div>
            <?php if(!$page_type && $custom_block && $static_block_tab):?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="custom-block-tab">
                    <?php echo $custom_block->toHtml(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After applying the fixes, I do not have an HTTP 500 ERROR anymore. However, the product page fails to display its content properly.

[image: Product page]

Edit 2: Here is the new error from my apache error log file:

> [Thu Nov 07 07:46:19.254058 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2258] [client 127.0.0.1:37799] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml:65\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include()\n#1 /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details), '/home/321257.cl...', Array)\n#2 /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/321257.cl...')\n#3 /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(668): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()\n#4 /home/321257.cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_h...\n'

Sincerely,
Toomas Goutt

Comment: cloudwaysapps.com/amukgacefe/public_html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml This File Line No. 18 Look Function Like getData()

Comment: This Function Getting Null So This issue is Generated

Comment: "This Function Getting Null So This issue is Generated" could you please explain this?

Comment: The line 18 says : $page_type = $_product->getData('product_page_type');

Comment: product_page_type not getting in product object

Comment: Would that mean that when I create the product, I need to select a specific "Product Page Type" ?

-Default
-Extended
-Full width
-Grid Image
-etc...

Comment: may be this is possible...not save that value and remove this line and check

Comment: Can you please update your details.phtml file's content in question ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya Edit has been made to the post with the current details.phtml file content

Comment: Can you please check still you're getting same error ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya Please see my second edit - I have included the new error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace this `$_product()` variable with `$_product` this in your code.

Line no : **65, 108, 137**

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if you'll get any other errors or that works for you.

Comment: You can approve my answer if this works for you. Thanks :)