# How to get current product in Magento 2.3.1 without deprecations

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3.1, deprecated

> ***Not a duplicate question, as the referenced original question uses deprecated classes.***

I want to get the current product in a Block / Model in `Magento 2.3.1`. I cannot directly use / inject / extend any deprecated classes like `Registry` / `AbstractProduct`. *[Must use DI and not ObjectManager](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly?noredirect=1&lq=1)*

What is the best alternative for this?

Comment: You can use this module flow. https://github.com/Vinai/module-current-product-example

Comment: @RohanHapani that seems like a manual fix? Registry had a quick solution for this and I'm not able to find a direct and recommended alternative for it.

Comment: No. It's proper way for get current product. But, still you can use by registry also. It's working in 2.3.1 If still not working then, you can use this module

Comment: I guess there's no direct alternative then? (Only a manual workaround?) And yeah, deprecated classes will work, but it is not good to use them anyways.

Comment: Is it useful for you? Then, I post as answer.

Comment: @RohanHapani No, I already came across that, but it's a manual fix for the issue.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution suggested at https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/

Also, there is discussion in the comment section of the article on the other alternative options.

Comment: This answer will become useless if the linked article goes down.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `id` in params,

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Or

```
$this->request->getParam('product_id'); // Use this class in construct() \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
```

> In your **Controller** file

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

public function execute()
{
    $this->request->getParam('product_id');
}
```

> To get `id` in `getParam()` you need to **pass it as hidden field in phtml file**

**For Example:-**

> in phtml file

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value=""> <!-- value should be your <?php echo $product_id ?> -->
```

> **In Observer & Plugin File:-** It depends on which event you want to observe and same goes for the plugin. If you're passing as hidden field and calling a observer on that particular event, you can get `id` as i mentioned above.

**In Block file:-** Since you don't want to use `Registry`, you can try using `$this->request->getParams()`.

Comment: From where would the id parameter get sent? Also, I need to use in a Block.

Comment: @AdarshM did you get solution? if not then on which page you want product id?

Comment: I want to use in any place. (Block/Plugin/Observer/Controller/etc)

Comment: in frontend or backend?

Comment: In the frontend.

Comment: if you could explain more specifically about what you're trying to achieve Or the functionality you want, it would be more easy to answer.

Comment: `getParam('product_id')` didn’t work for me, but `getParam('id')` did.

Answer (score -2):

You can get Current Product by creating custom module or by object manager, But I am not refer to use as Object Manager

**1. Using Module**

Create file app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product.php and add following Code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
        protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }    

}
?>
```

Now you can get the current product in phtml file.

```
// print current product data
$currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct();
echo $currentProduct->getName()
```

**2. Using Object Manager directly phtml**

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
$currentProduct = $registry->registry('current_product');
echo $currentProduct->getName();
echo $currentProduct->getSku();
```

Comment: I cannot use Registry (neither ObjectManger) as it's deprecated in M2.3.1. (mentioned in the question)