# How to add logout on header links in Magento 2.3.X

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, header

Can anyone tell me how to add 'sign out' option after the user is logged in on header links in Magento 2.3.X https://prnt.sc/oqe2ue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom logout link in header than,You can add below code in test.phtml and than call this phtml in layout

```
 <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
 <?php $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');?>

 <?php if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()):?>       
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout') ?>">Logout</a></li>     
 <?php endif;  ?>
```

Add this phtml to lyout default.xml in theme

```
  <referenceContainer name="header.panel.wrapper" >
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="nameOfBlock" as="header" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"/>
  </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Don't use Object Manager instance directly check this for more details:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Comment: Okk...than get the session of customer using controller or any other

Comment: yes create data file or block file and using `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext` this dependency we are getting customer login or not

Comment: Thanx... my work is done. Can u guys tell me how to overirde block file in app folder. i want to override AuthorizationLink.php of /vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account.

Comment: You can check this.... https://magenticians.com/magento-2-override-block/