# How to get "product url" for multi website in sales email template

Tags: magento2, sales-order, multistore, base-url, multi-website

From my magento2 backend i created 2 website. 1st default website xxxx.com 2nd website is yyyy.com. 
In my sales order email template, added

```
$_order = $_item->getOrder();
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
echo $product->getProductUrl();
```

When i place order from 2nd website (i.e.,) yyyy.com, product Base URL getting xxxx.com

Please let me know how to get base URL for multiwebsite sales email template.

Comment: Could you please specify where exactly you added the code above?

Comment: in my child them/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried may ways but i got only Default base url. So 1st i get store BaseUrl and and get UrlKey, then i combined.

```
$base_url = $_item->getStore(2)->getBaseUrl();
$product_key = $_item->getProduct()->getUrlKey(); 
echo $base_url . $product_key;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$product = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId($your_store_id)->load($_item->getProductId());
```

Comment: i tried this too. still geting same base_url. For my clarification let me know how to find "$your_store_id" ?

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-default-store-id-of-website-by-website-id-magento-2/ 
follow this to get default store id based on website id.

Comment: i had tried this, but still getting default Base URL

Answer (score 0):

Access your DB and browse your store table. you will get the complete picture what store do you want.

Then Try this:

```
$product = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId($your_store_id)->load($_item->getProductId());
```

Comment: i tried above method, still geting default base_url

Answer (score 0):

In case that you are using template from *Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.html*

You can simply do:

```php
$_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl()
```

this works fine in my fresh Magento 2.3.3

*Note from me:* Please don't use Object Manager, especially in templates.

Comment: Please let me know, why you are saying not to use "Object Manager"?

Comment: @Priya you can read about this in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Comment: @Priya does my answer help you?

Comment: Yeah, Thank you

Comment: But for my Question i did not get answer.

Comment: so $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() still return url for default website?

Comment: yeah, still getting same. Please refer - https://prnt.sc/pql2cg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100523/discussion-between-priya-and-underser).