# Magento 2: Get Product URL in Shipment Email

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I was trying to link the product name in the shipment mail to the product on our page, so the customer can click on the product name in the shipment mail.

I have tried with

> $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl()

but getProduct() returns null.
The same code worked for the order confirmation mail.

Does anybody know how I can get the product URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
<?php 
    $_item = $block->getItem(); 
    $product_key = $_item->getProduct()->getUrlKey();    
    echo $product_key;
?>
```

More information :-

[How to get "product url" for multi website in sales email template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294101/how-to-get-product-url-for-multi-website-in-sales-email-template)

Thanks...

Comment: Hello @whiterabbit this answer helpful or not ???

Comment: Hi, so I already tried this one, but it doesn't work for shipping or creditmemo mails. It only works for confirmation mails, because $_item->getProduct() returns null for shipping and creditmemo mails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $_item->getOrderItem()->getProduct() in Shipment & Credit Memo email templates.

```
$_item->getOrderItem()->getProduct()->getProductUrl();
```