# How to getproduct url for sales email order template in multi website

Tags: magento2, order-email, product-urls, multi-website

I want to get producturl in `sales order email` template in multi website.

I have used

```
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
$product->setStoreId($_item->getStoreId());

$_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
if($childProd = current($_item->getChildrenItems()))
{
   $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($childProd->getProduct(), 'category_page_list')->resize(80, 80)->getUrl();
}
else
{
   $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_item->getProduct(), 'category_page_list')->resize(80, 80)->getUrl();
}

?>
<tr>      
    <td class="item-image">
       <img src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" alt="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" />
    </td>   
    <td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>">      
        <p class="product-name"><a href="<?= $product->getProductUrl(); ?>" style="color:#000;"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>

        <p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU') ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>

        <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
            <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                <dt style="font-size: 13px;font-family: Tahoma,sans-serif;"><strong><em><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $option['label'] ?> : </em></strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  nl2br($option['value']) ?></dt>               
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
            <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
    </td>
    <td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?></td>
    <td class="item-price">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

in my `Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml` file

it's getting default **base url**.

Comment: Check with this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly.....You have to inject specific class into phtml's block classes. As it is magento's default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can get product object from `$_item`.

No need to load product again in default.phtml. Try below solution

```
<?= $_item->getproduct()->getProductUrl() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Store ID using this function `setStoreId($_item->getStoreId())` like..

```
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
$product->setStoreId($_item->getStoreId());

echo $product->getProductUrl();
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Hi, I tried this method, by base url geting default url.. i need to get second website url

Comment: Can you please update your code in your question ?

Comment: I have updated. Please check above. Thank you

Comment: Can you please set this line after product->load() ? **$product->setStoreId($_item->getStoreId());**

Comment: Yeah, i added . Stil it getting same base url.. Now i updated in my question.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have Right store ID ?

Comment: yeah. In this i get image, that is came from right storeID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100518/discussion-between-priya-and-kishan-savaliya).

Answer (score 0):

I tried may ways but i got only Default base url. So 1st i get store BaseUrl and and get UrlKey, then i combined.

```
$base_url = $_item->getStore(2)->getBaseUrl();
$product_key = $_item->getProduct()->getUrlKey(); 
echo $base_url . $product_key;
```