# Magento 2.2 Can we use Object Manager in Controller or Block?

Tags: product, magento2.2, object-manager

To get product data, I am using object manager in my controller, but I read in docs that we should not use it directly.

```
<?php 
 pubic function execute()
 {
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $id = '10';
     $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')-load($id);
     // My code here
 }
?>
```

Please suggest me a way how to use Object Manager in controller or block?

Comment: i  believe this is a useless question posted here, you should check before post something on stack.
Check this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly/140823#140823

Comment: Where?  Please share link.

Comment: already shared, please check above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the ObjectManager directly!

Exception from the rule are:

- in static magic methods like `__wakeup`, `serialize`, etc
- in case you should make backward compatibility of constructor
- in global scope, like in fixtures of integration test.
- in class that needs only for creation of object like factory, proxy ,
  etc.

You could use it in Factories, but except that you should inject the Object Manager in the Constructor first then you can use its object in your method:

**Step 1:**  declare `private` object:

```
private $_objectManager;
```

**Step 2:**  inject in the constructor and initialize it:

```
public function __construct(
    ..............,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    ..............
) {
    ..............
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    ..............
}
```

**Step 3:** use in your `execute`/`any` method:

```
    public function create() 
   {
        ...............
        $id = '10';
        $product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')-load($id);
        -------
    }
```

Hope it helps..!!