# Is there a better practice than using Object Manager?

Tags: magento2

I was wondering if there was a better way to use the resources than object manager, here is how i'm currently using the category factory's. I am very new to Magento.

```
<?php

namespace XX\TierPriceSummary\Block\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{

    protected $_customerGroupsCollection;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_resource;
    private   $storeID = 1;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroupsCollection,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerGroupsCollection = $customerGroupsCollection;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

    private function getProductTierPrice($SubCategoryID,$pID,$groupID){
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();    
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
        $categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
        $categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');

        //do something
        } 

}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. You should use dependency injection like how **ProductRepository** is being used in your example.

Using ObjectManager is discouraged by Magento.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html

```
<?php 
namespace XX\TierPriceSummary\Block\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{

protected $_customerGroupsCollection;
protected $_productRepository;
protected $_categoryFactory;
protected $_resource;
private   $storeID = 1;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroupsCollection,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_customerGroupsCollection = $customerGroupsCollection;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;

    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
}

private function getProductTierPrice($SubCategoryID,$pID,$groupID){
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();    

    $categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
    $categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');

    //do something with $this->_categoryFactory
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

By putting the class definitions in your `__construct` method, Magento will automatically inject them when the class is created. Here is how you would do so:

```php
<?php

namespace XX\TierPriceSummary\Block\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{

    protected $_customerGroupsCollection;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_resource;
    private   $storeID = 1;

    protected $_categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroupsCollection,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory, //new definition
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerGroupsCollection = $customerGroupsCollection;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory; //assign new definition to a protected/private var
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

    private function getProductTierPrice($SubCategoryID,$pID,$groupID){
        $this->_categoryFactory->create(); //use the category factory
    }
```

Comment: I did try that but i got [2020-01-17 09:05:57] main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: XX\TierPriceSummary\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Index, Argument 5 passed to XX\TierPriceSummary\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory, array given, called in /domains/gaz.development.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116 [] []

Comment: Run setup:di:compile

Comment: @Adam, thats normal. You have to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. If it still fails, then you have to delete the folder `generated/code` and execute the command again.

Comment: You wouldn't have to run `setup:upgrade`. **At worst**, given the example error from OP, you just run `rm -rf generated/code/*` (in developer mode; in production mode you'd run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`) to force the classes to be regenerated.

Comment: @AdamMellen, I faced this error very often and `setup:upgrade` is the solution. (I am in developer mode)

Comment: I needed to run Run setup:di:compile