# Magento2 - When customer reaches a .phtml block, log them out automatically if they're logged in

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

Is there a way where in a check through a `.phtml` block to see that the customer is logged in, and If so, automatically log them out - please no `observers` or `modules`.

I feel confident that I've seen a solution that talked about auto log out somewhere  vaguely, but I am unable to find this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->logout();
```

[source](https://www.tutorialsplane.com/magento-2-logout-customer-programmatically/)

Comment: I read that using object manager from a .phtml isn't that great for reasons - I forget what they are. I see people warning against doing that in other answers. However, thank you for your help. Is there another solution that may use this not as directly?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Answer (score 0):

**In your block class:**

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}
public function logoutCustomer()
{
    $customerId = $this->customerSession->getId();
    if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->customerSession->logout()->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl())->setLastCustomerId($customerId);
        return "Customer logout successfully";
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Call function in your phtml file:**

```
<?php $block->logoutCustomer(); ?>
```

Comment: Hello there! I have a question to your solution or anyone who may have an idea about what block class means exactly. I noticed you used a block class... where would that be located? I have my phtml referenced in a .phtml - I do like how you're not using objectManager directly.