# Is it okay to use $this->helper(...) in phtml files?

Tags: magento2, helper, object-manager

A question on using `$this->helper(...)` in phtml files:

- It returns something like this: `ObjectManager->get(...) (Singleton)`
- I'm aware it's [bad practice to use Object Manager phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly), but technically it's not using Object Manager directly.

Does this make it okay to use?

After doing some research I see:

> Object manager should be used only in factories and then as injected in a constructor.
> The advantage of using this is less code to write. But this does not make it OK.
> The fact that this is still used in the core, is because it didn't get refactored yet. I hope it will be.

This is in response to using `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()` specifically mind you. For `$this->helper()` it appears to be more unclear. Magento does still appear to use this in it's core.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No use of **$this->helper()** call is deprecated in you should use a view model instead(even though some core file still uses it) . Even use of $this is discouraged in PHTML , **$block** should be used.

**Using view model is best way** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html#when-to-use-view-models

You can inject the class you want to use in PHTML and create a public getter method for that class

Magento considers even helpers as anti pattern https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/common-programming-bp.html#avoid-creating-helper-classes

Comment: Love it, thanks very much. Clears it right up.