# how do I change this sql query to magento get data method?

Tags: magento2, database, query

I have below sql query, how do I turn this to Magento get data method to retrieve data? Please help

```
SELECT sales_order.increment_id, sales_order_payment.additional_information FROM sales_order LEFT JOIN 
            sales_order_payment ON sales_order.entity_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id 
            WHERE sales_order_payment.method = 'opayment' AND sales_order.updated_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the below query:**

```
    /**
     * @var $orderCollection Collection
     */
    $orderCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $orderCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['sales_order_payment' => $orderCollection->getTable('sales_order_payment')],
        "(main_table.entity_id = {$orderCollection->getTable('sales_order_payment')}.parent_id" .
        " )",
        [
            $orderCollection->getTable('sales_order_payment') . '.additional_information'
        ]
    )->where($orderCollection->getTable('sales_order_payment').'.method = ?','payflowpro');
    $orderCollection->getSelect()->where('main_table.updated_at >= ?',$orderCollection->getConnection()->getDateSubSql(
        new \Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'),
        '30',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INTERVAL_MINUTE
    ));
```

Comment: thanks! can you help how to implement OrderCollection to the the code, I am confuse how to set the element up at the page

Comment: THANKS! YOU ARE MY LIFE SAVER

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection` to run custom SQL queries

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$query = "SELECT sales_order.increment_id, sales_order_payment.additional_information FROM sales_order LEFT JOIN 
            sales_order_payment ON sales_order.entity_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id 
            WHERE sales_order_payment.method = 'opayment' AND sales_order.updated_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE";
$Data =  $resource->getConnection()->fetchAll($query);
```

Via Dependency Injection

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    }

public function RunQuery(){
    $query = "SELECT sales_order.increment_id, sales_order_payment.additional_information FROM sales_order LEFT JOIN 
                sales_order_payment ON sales_order.entity_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id 
                WHERE sales_order_payment.method = 'opayment' AND sales_order.updated_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE";
    $Data =  $this->_resource->getConnection()->fetchAll($query);
}
```

Comment: If I don't use ObjectManager directly, how do I using Dependency injection?

Comment: I have updated it in my answer

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me why this way is better than using ObjectManager Directly?

Comment: [read this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)