# How to get Product Salable quantity by productId in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, stock, inventory

[image]

How to get product salable qty by productId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to get sku from product id then you can get salable qty by sku**

```
<?php
namespace Mital\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model;

use Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku; 
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class GetSalableQuantityDataBySku
{
    private $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;

    public function __construct(
        GetSalableQuantityDataBySku $getSalableQuantityDataBySku,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productrepository
    ) 
    {
        $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku = $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
        $this->productrepository = $productrepository;
    }

    public function getProductSalableQty()
    {   
        $productid = 12;
        $sku = $this->getProductDataUsingId($productid);
        $salable = $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute($sku);
        echo json_encode($salable);
    }

    public function getProductDataUsingId($productid)
    {
       $product = $this->productrepository->getById($productid);
       return $product->getSku();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku');

$qty = $StockState->execute($product->getSku()); //Being product a product model loaded by your id
$quantity= $qty[0]['qty']; // This is the salable qty
```

Comment: This is useful.but objectmanager method is not good practice

Comment: Hello @Alshihab why is it not a good practice? Thanks

Comment: According to Magento's core group, you should not use Object Manager in modules because it makes the class lose dependency injection.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly